# Unknown unique symbol type

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have an *random* type error that i didn't initialized, I have declared my types in my Redux endpoints as such `string | undefined` . But when i tried to call the query hook, it mysteriously shows a `unique symbol` type.

```
Argument of type '{ id: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | unique symbol | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

Source of error

```
import { useGetThemeQuery } from "@/state/api";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const AllProjects = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  // Check if id is defined before calling the query
  const { data } = useGetThemeQuery({ id }); <--- ERROR HERE
  return (
    <div>
      {data?.map((project) => (
        <p>{project.type}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllProjects;
```

My redux endpoints

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import type { Project } from "./types";
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL }),
  reducerPath: "main",
  tagTypes: ["Projects", "Themes"],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getProject: build.query<Array<Project>, void>({
      query: () => "/",
      providesTags: ["Projects"],
    }),
    getTheme: build.query<Array<Project>, string | undefined>({  <---TYPE ERROR 
      query: (theme) => `themes/${theme}`,
      providesTags: ["Themes"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetProjectQuery, useGetThemeQuery } = api;
```

Comment: Does this question depend on redux? If so please tag it as such.  If not, please [edit] so the code is a [mre] that doesn't depend on third-party frameworks.

Comment: Don't wrap in brackets: `useGetThemeQuery(id);`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with `skipToken`

```
import { useGetThemeQuery } from "@/state/api";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { skipToken } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';

const AllProjects = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  // Check if id is defined before calling the query
  const { data } = useGetThemeQuery(id || skipToken);
  return (
    <div>
      {data?.map((project) => (
        <p>{project.type}</p>
      ))}
    </div>s
  );
};

export default AllProjects;
```